# Using the SUM Function in Excel with N/A values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to create a formula for the Total cell at the bottom of a column. The problem is that some of the values in the blocks I am adding up are N/A values. (All the values in the blocks are also formulas themselves, with IF statements).

No matter what we have tried so far, we can't get the Total cell to calculate the total. We have tried the following:

- `SUM(IF(ISNA(A1:A4),0,A1:A4))`
- `SUMIF(A1:A4,"<>#N/A")`

Is it because the cells we are calculating a total for are formulas themselves? What are we missing?

Comment: What happens with `=SUMIF(A1:A4,"<>#N/A")`?

Comment: Did you try entering the first formula as an array formula, i.e. with Ctrl+Shift+Enter?

Answer (score 3):

=SUM(SUMIF(A1:A4,{"<0",">0"}))

If all your values are non-negative then simply:

=SUMIF(A1:A4,">0")

Regards

Comment: Neither of those worked either. :(

Comment: @LindiDeBeer, this formula definitely works.  Did you copy and paste it exactly?

Comment: Can you expand on "Niether of those worked....."? In what way, did you get zero as a result....or an error....or some other result that was incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that XOR LX answer works and is probably the easiest solution.

An alternative would be

```
=SUM(IF(ISERROR(A1:A4),0,A1:A4))
```

which is an array formula entered by pressing ctrl+shift+enter